# Why is CSS border different on Google Chrome?

Tags: css, border

why is border-style different on google chrome `Version 84.0.4147.89 (Official Build) (64-bit)`
unlike Mozilla browser `79.0b9 (64-bit)`.

Here is a screenshot:

Google Chrome

[image]

Mozilla

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the [border-style spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/#propdef-border-style) doesn't define how the spacing of the dashed borders should be done, so you end up with each browser implementing it a bit differently.

> There is no control over the spacing of the dots and dashes, nor over
> the length of the dashes. Implementations are encouraged to choose a
> spacing that makes the corners symmetrical.